# Getting undefined when trying to display individual mapped data

Tags: react-native, dictionary

I am using a useEffect to fetch data when screen renders. I am able to fetch and console log data, but when I try to display individual data I get undefined...

My code:

```
// useState
const [data, setData] = useState([]);


// UseEffect to fetch data
useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, [])


// Fetch data
const getData = async () => {
  try{
    await axios.get('http://url')
    .then(res => {
      const Data = JSON.stringify(res.data);
      setData([Data]);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};


// Render data
const renderData = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      { data && data?.map((item) => (
        <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 12 }}>@{item.id}</Text>
        <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 12 }}>@{item.username}</Text>
    ))}
    </View>
  )
}
```

When I console.log(item), I get data like: {"id":1,"username":"test_user"}

when I console.log(item.id) or console.log(item.username), I get: undefined

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: Where are you placing those console.log calls?  Should you be parsing instead of stringifying? Maybe the data is already JSON.

Comment: Are you sure the item is `{"id":1,"username":"test_user"}` and you're getting undefined while using `item.id`?

Comment: Ahh my mistake. didn't need to stringify data. My bad, thanks for your time!!